# list_first_entry array of linked list linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, linked-list

I have a struct like

```
struct my_struct {
     struct list_head queues[NB_QUEUES];
};
```

I would like to access at the first element of one of the queue (index is computed but I take 2 for the example, which is < NB_QUEUES) like the following (which works without arrays)

```
struct list_head t = list_first_entry(&foo->queues[2], struct my_struct, ???);
```

What am I supposed to do to obtain the first element of the queue at the index 2 ? I didn't find anything which compils

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, your code isn't very clear. Let's talk about a more generic example:

1. I have NB_QUEUES queues. I'm just going to store these as a global variable:

   ```
   struct list_head queues[NB_QUEUES];
   ```
2. We'll want to make sure that our lists are initialized. We can do that statically with `LIST_HEAD_INIT`, or at runtime with `INIT_LIST_HEAD`.

   ```
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<NB_QUEUES; ++i)
       INIT_LIST_HEAD(&queues[i]);
   ```
3. We can then push an object of type element into one of these queues:

   ```
   struct element {
       struct list_head list;
       int data;
       float more_data;
   };

   struct element *v = kmalloc(sizeof(*v), GFP_KERNEL);
   v->data = 4;
   v->more_data = 7.2;

   list_add(&v.list, &queues[2]);
   ```
4. Later, we can then access the first element in the list.

   ```
   struct element *q = list_first_entry(&queues[2], struct element, list);
   ```

   The `list` argument is from the name of the member of `struct element` that we used when we inserted this object into the linked list.